# Transformation of a theta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions

Given $\Theta(\tau)=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}exp(2\pi in² \tau)$ and $\tau \in \mathbb H$

I am trying to prove the following identity:

$\Theta(-\frac{1}{2\pi})=\sqrt{\frac{\tau}{i}}\Theta(\frac{\tau}{2})$

Expanding the sum I get the following:

$\Theta(-\frac{1}{2\pi})=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z}exp(-in² \tau)$

Might be a dumb question but how do I get the factor $\sqrt{\frac{\tau}{i}}$ from that sum

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As currently written, your question is malformed. We can see this because
$$ \Theta(-1/2\pi)$$
is a constant, while
$$ \sqrt{\frac{\tau}{i}} \Theta(\tau/2)$$
is a (nonconstant) function of $\tau$.

It is likely that what you meant was to prove that
$$\Theta(i/\tau) = \sqrt{\tau} \Theta(i\tau),$$
or an equivalent transformation. This is a classically studied transformation, used by Riemann in one of his proofs the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$. This is traditionally proved through Poisson summation on the definition of $\Theta(\tau)$.

Comment: At least there was no typo on my part. This is exactly how the question was given to me. I will send that particular guy an email and may (or may not) come back to the question :P Do you know of any book/literature where I can find a proof of the functional equation above ?

Comment: @XPenguen A good thing to look for is for Dirichlet's proof of the functional equation. A quick google search using these terms (and "theta" and "poisson") led me to [this pdf](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/ant13-9.pdf) as the top hit. This functional equation is essentially what's proved in section 9.2 there --- note that the pdf defines the theta function slightly differently, concerning the imaginary component $i$. But the proof is essentially the same.

Comment: The most elementary way is to extend $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-b(t-a)^2} dt =b^{-1/2} C$ ($C= \sqrt{\pi}$) from $a$ real to $a $ complex to obtain the Fourier transform of $e^{-b t^2}$ and the Fourier series of $\sum_n e^{-b(t-n)^2}$ as well as the Poisson summation formula with $t=0$ @XPenguen